# How to calculate parity of a 32bits number in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, parity

I need to calculate the parity of a 32 bits number and return it. To do this I must use XOR, SHR,SETP(or similar) and movzx. Somebody have an idea ?

Comment: Are you talking about a particlar ISA here?  If so, please add that info to your question.

Comment: And some code. Stackoverflow is there to help you with problems with _your code_, not providing you with _your work_.

Comment: Hint: check out the x86 condition code bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to do this, of course. If you decide to use the hardware parity flag, keep in mind that it only checks the low 8 bits. A solution using this approach might be to process your 32 bit input as four 8 bit values, and use `XOR` on the partial results:

`p(31:0) = p(31:24) ^ p(23:16) ^ p(15:8) ^ p(7:0)`

To get the 8 bit units, you can use `SHR` and to get the partial values you can `XOR`, use the `SETP`. This should be enough to get you started.

Another, possibly more efficient, option is to XOR the bytes and grab the parity of them:

`p(31:0) = p(31:24 ^ 23:16 ^ 15:8 ^ 7:0)`

Comment: Hint hint!  Check out the omplete set of x86 CC bits!

Comment: @IraBaxter I guess I need more hints :) I have been talking about using `PF` all along, not sure what other flag you can use...

Comment: @Jester: My goof, I thought  you weren't using the hardware parity flag, AND that it applied to all 32 bits (not just the LS byte).  Suitably self-chastened, your answer is pretty good but the notation p(...) wasn't clear to me.  +1 for having the right answer and hanging in there!

Comment: Probably the right answer (only 2 xors): mov eax, <value>; mov ebx, eax; shr ebx 16; xor eax, ebx; mov ebx, eax; shr ebx, 8; xor eax, ebx; jp ...

Comment: @IraBaxter and you can simplify further by using the 8 bit registers: `xor al, ah`.

Comment: @Jester: I'm not sure how that is a simplification.  That wont work for the 16 bit halves and it isn't clear that "xor al, ah" is a "simplification" of "xor eax, ebx".   (Actually, it might be a pessimazation: partial register updates [e.g. updating the AL part of EAX] can cause instruction pipelining stalls).

Comment: @IraBaxter it is a simplification because you can drop the `mov ebx,eax; shr ebx, 8`. Partial register stall isn't applicable here.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code:

```
    mov ebx, 1234 ;Replace this number with the value of which you want to know the parity
    mov cx, 4
a:
    or bl,  bl
    lahf
    ror eax, 8
    ror ebx, 8
    loop a
    xor ah, al
    ror eax, 16
    xor al, ah
    rol eax, 8
    xor ah, al
    and ah, 4
    sahf ;now the parity flag is defined
```

Comment: It's much easier to just horizontally XOR the original data down to 8 bits, instead of getting the parity for each 8 bits separately and then XORing that down to 1 byte.  e.g. `mov edx, eax` / `shr edx, 16` / `xor eax, edx` / `xor al, ah` / read PF.